# Can't load the date field after rendering new page with error has happened

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

When submit my form with error message it will rendered new.html.erb (render action:  "new") after loaded new page with error, multidatepicker field in script can't load at the same time route is showing as index page.

In new page,
 datepicker `class = "pick hasDatepicker".` routes `localhost:3000/leaves/new` (new page)

after rendered new page in create action with error message,

datepicker `class = "pick"`. routes `localhost:3000/leaves` (index page)

What can i do for that ?...

**leavescontroller.rb**

```
def create  # Create a new record in the Leave table

        @leave = current_user.leaves.create leave_params
        # @leave.user_id = session[:user_id]
        @leave_dates = params[:datePick].split(',')
        @leave.start_date = @leave_dates.first
        @leave.end_date = @leave_dates.last

        respond_to do |format|
          if @leave.save
            ..//conditions
          else
            format.html { render action:  "new" }
            format.json { render json: @leave.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
```

**new.html.rb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/datepicker'%>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                return [day != 0 && day != 6];
            }, // For disabling all "Sundays"
            dateFormat : "d/m/yy",
            maxDate : "+3m",
            minDate : "0m",
            multidate : true,
            addDisabledDates : <%= raw @holidays %>
        });
    });
</script>
<body >


<div id="newentryrow">
            <div id="newentrytext">
              <label>Select Dates :</label>
            </div>
            <div id="newentryfield" >
              <%= text_field_tag 'datePick', nil, placeholder: 'Select dates' ,class: 'pick', autoComplete: "off", :readonly => true %><br />
              <label>Select multiple dates if you want to apply more than one day leave…</label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: try keeping your multidatespicker outside `$(function() {});` directly under script and let me know if it helps?

Comment: I was find that solution, Inside multiDatepicker I have used @holidays  variable that is only present in new action as instance variable, when execute render new section in create else part , that instance variable need to present in create action also, that is the mistake in my code. thank you for your help.